# HTML5 header before body?

Tags: html

I have been using HTML4 for quite some time. I've heard of HTML5 for quite a while but never got around to reading the updated standard and it's new tags. What I would like to know is if I put the header tag before the body tag (and after the head tag), will this be valid? I know that in HTML4 you required to use divs (for instance header and container) to separate the sections of the page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No. `<header>`-tags mark the header of arbitrary sections on your site. Don't confuse them with the website's `<head>` section that contains scripts, meta-tags, etc. `<header>`-tags belong into the `<body>`-tag. The basic structure of a `<head>` followed by a `<body>` has not changed in HTML5.

http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/sections.html#the-header-element

Comment: To OP: Note that `<header>` (and footer) does not necessarily mean "my website's header", it has a purpose and you can have multiple headers per page. `<div>` tags can still be appropriate for banners/logos. Just thought I'd say something because it looks like you've made the assumption that HTML5 documents go `<header /><body /><footer />`, but in fact it is nothing like that.